# about conjure-up openstack-novalxd localhost style in 1 physical server

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

Is it have any risk in case running conjure-up openstack-novalxd localhost style in 1 physical server and working as production cloud ?

My physical server spec:

```
CPU 8Core/16Thread
RAM 32GB
SSD : 120GB for OS
SSD : 480GBx3 for ZFS-Raidz (Running conjure-up).
```

Answer (score 0):

Single machine horsepower (vertical scaling) doesn't matter if that single machine or one of the main services goes down.

For production environment, you need to deploy some level of redundancy and high availability with separate storage nodes (block and object) as shown here:
https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/install-guide-ubuntu/overview.html
and scale it horizontally (additional node provisioning), separate controller nodes, etc...

Additional youtube resource that might be of help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lz2tAt5Vf3U